# Easy way to create a simple react+redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I know we can use `create-react-app` to easily create a react.js app.

Also I see this simple redux sample: https://github.com/jackielii/simplest-redux-example

but is there kind of "create-react-with-redux-app" to easily create app?

Comment: There are some tutorials on how you setup redux. I think you really need to understand it. It's normal that Redux - based apps are hard to setup at first but it helps you out in the long run. You'll need to set it up yourself because you will be the one to control the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind that `Redux` is just a library, so, you can continue using `creare-react-app` and then just add `Redux`, but, if you also want to automate this simple task, then, just add [`create-react-app-add-redux`](https://github.com/eenewbsauce/create-react-app-add-redux)

```js
// Install
npm i -g create-react-app
npm i -g create-react-app-add-redux
```

```js
// usage
create-react-app my-app

cd my-app

add-redux
```